# Local blockchain vs. centralized database in a smart home environment

Tags: iot, blockchain

I am working with a smart home (IoT) environment that creates sensible data and I want to secure the immutability by storing the hash of that data on a public blockchain.

I want to use a local blockchain within the smart home environment to store data produced by IoT devices. The reason for using a private local blockchain instead of a public one is that I want to keep the user's data private.

Another approach would be to use a centralized database system to store all the data of the smart home environment and take the hash of the entire DB to store it on the public ledger.

**Are there reasons for using a blockchain over a centralized system in this case?**

The only benefit I could come up with is that the hash of the blockchain is already present whereas the hash of the centralized DB has to be calculated and could take a while.

Answer (score 0):

Blockchain does not only has a property of immutability but also have the property of distributed ledger, secure transaction, and pseudo-anonymous. Due to the distributed ledger, the data can be access at any time providing no zero downtime. All the transactions are verified and secure by the other nodes the verification is done with the help of Proof of Work done by the nodes. All the transactions are pseudo-anonymous this help in the form of the transaction, as no one knows who is initiating the transaction and who is receiving the transaction.